# Testing Sharepoint with IE 11

Tags: 2013, internet-explorer

I'm pretty new to this and wanted everyone's take and experience in doing so. I need to test IE11 to find any issues of how it works in unison with Sharepoint 2013. We are currently on IE 10, and as I mentioned, wanted to test IE 11 prior to making the upgrade.

Below are some of the tests that I thought of:

check in and checkout settings - to and from local drafts,
saving files directly from PC to the sites
setting up network places
exporting files
working with panel
pic libraries
form libraries
InfoPath
Workflows
HTML

Based on everyone else's experience what other tests have you all performed. I have a rookie question as well. I have been told to also test in Standard mode. I am assuming this is an IE setting? Any tips and clarification would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE 11 will support all of the same features as IE 10, however IE 11 is only supported with SharePoint when the SharePoint site(s) is added to Compatibility View.

There should be very little to no reason to explicitly test IE 11 functionality with SharePoint 2013.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint sites work fine with IE 11. Some features of "some" sites however, would work only in the compatibility mode.

"Standard mode" probably means by not adding the site in compatibility mode.